# Replace blank and null values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
Select 
   impressions,
   COALESCE(u.company,u.email) AS Publisher
FROM users AS u
```

Here, the company field has a company name or a Null or a Blank value. I don't want Publisher column to have a blank or a null value.

The above statement works for NULL as it returns the u.email value in that case. But it does not work for blank values. So I tried doing:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(u.company,''),u.email)
```

This does not seem to work as blank values are not replaced by email.

Can somebody please point out where I am going wrong?
Is there an alternative?

Comment: It's uglier...but case when u.company is null then u.email  when trim(u.company) = '' then u.email else u.company end

Comment: What datatype is `u.company`?

Comment: @AaronD- u.company is varchar(256)

Comment: @Twelfth- Need to give this a shot...

Answer (score 1):

maybe this:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(u.company,u.email),u.email)
```

Comment: But won't it compare u.company and u.email in this case?
I am trying get rid of null and blank values in the company field and replace it with email.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying correctly.

COALESCE evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expressions that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

So this would seem to be why your statement works for NULL.  In the case of it not working for blank values are because a blank value is still technically a value if evaluated as a string.

Also, if you are referring to the Database table not being able to have a null or blank value you can set a table to not accept a null value by:

ALERT TABLE [Table name] ALTER COLUMN [column] INTEGER NOT NULL

Integer obviously would be replaced if its not of that type.  Doing this can trigger problems in code that communicates with the database though if it isnt written properly to handle null values sent to a db.

To replace values in a certain column with values that are in another column such as replacing company values with email values you could try.

```
UPDATE [table name] t
SET t.[column name] =
(SELECT [other column name from table2] FROM [table2 name] v
WHERE t.[column name] = v.[column name from table2]);
```

Comment: Your are correct but is there is no way of replacing the blank and null values  in company column with email?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit dirtier, but it'll work.  Just define each case that you want to replace in a case statement (use trim in case someone put in 2 or 3 spaces).  Probably not the optimal solution though

```
case when u.company is null then u.email 
     when trim(u.company) = '' then u.email 
else u.company 
end
```

Comment: Maybe not optimal, but this does make sense!!